# Why canSetSessionPreset always returns true when device can't support the preset?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

We want to use Apple's [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession) to check if the device camera supports 4K, but have no success so far.

```swift
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let supported = captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160)
    
    if(supported){
        print("supported")
    }
    else{
        // Somehow, never comes here.
        print("unsupported")
    }
```

The above code/api always returns true even if the device can't support 4K preset *(e.g. iPod Touch 7th generation)*.

In case this can't be fixed, Is there any other way of checking 4K camera?

I highly value your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the canSetSessionPreset() method. For now, I have solved my problem using DiscoverySession https://gist.github.com/simonkim/4c7a20fb978c9dfc350b6bb4c1512332